# Is there any way to make each matrix column have only one value in python?

Tags: python, numpy

This array has 6 columns.

```
u = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

I am looking for a way to make each matrix column have a single 1 value. The first and the fifth columns meet my condition because they have a single 1 value.

So, the process may use random to delete some 1s such as in the third column that has two 1s and the fourth column that has 3 1s. For the second and sixth columns, there is no change.

My expected result after randomly deleting 1 in some columns may look like this:

```
u = np.array ([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
               [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Can anyone show me how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you essentially looking for the reduced-row echelon form of a non-square matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np

u = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])

# Iterate through the columns
for i in range(u.shape[1]):
    #find 1s
    valid_indices = np.where(u[:, i] == 1)[0]
    if len(valid_indices) > 0:
        # Generate random index
        one_index = np.random.choice(valid_indices)
        # Put a 0 in all 1s
        u[u[:, i] == 1, i] = 0
        # Put the 1
        u[one_index, i] = 1

print(u)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cumsum to mask the first occurrence of a 1 in each column.  If you want to keep the last one, you can use negative steps indexing:

```
u=np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])

u[::-1,:] *= np.cumsum(u[::-1,:],axis=0) == 1

print(u)

[[1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0]]
```

To only keep the first one use the matrix directly (without negative stepping):

```
u *= np.cumsum(u,axis=0) == 1

[[1 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```